# How to pass function through module options to plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

how could i pass function to plugin in module by module options? Is some way to extend nuxt app by global property to pass func in module file or something else?

Problem example:

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
modules: [
  [
    'some-module',
    {
      foo: () => {
        // Do something 
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

`module.js`

```js
module.exports = function (options) {
  this.addPlugin({
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'plugin.js'),
      fileName: 'bar-plugin.client.js',
      options,
  });
}
```

`plugin.js`

```js
const options = JSON.parse(`<%= JSON.stringify(options, null, 2) %>`); // <-- Here we pluck out all the options using Lodash templates and JSON.stringify() but func "foo" is undefined(?)

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  incject('somePluginName', handler(app, options)
}
```

I tried extend nuxt app in module hook `modules:done` like:

```js
this.nuxt.hook('modules:done', moduleContainer => {
   moduleContainer.nuxt.app.$foo = options.foo
})
```

But `app` is undefined :/